# How to use ES6 import (client-side JS)

Tags: es6-modules, vee-validate

I am trying to use VeeValidate and the examples show the usage of ES6 import like this:

```
import { Validator } from 'vee-validate';
```

My understanding is that this works only with npm and not with CDN. I want to just write client-side js and not use node js. Do I have to look into something like browserify or webpack?

I tried to copy the javascript from the CDN link and just make it a local js file for importing, but could not get it working. Did it not work because I did not have export statements?

Comment: If you copy in your local you need to specify path also by default it looks inside node_modules.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first thing to do is to **put `type="module"` as an attribute of your `<script>`** tag

Full example:

```html
<script type='module' src='module-a.mjs' /> 

<script type="module">
  import * as moduleA from 'module-a.mjs'
</script>
```

You may want to add a `.mjs` extension to explicitly tell that this file is a js module and avoid syntax errors in your IDE.

Currently import / export syntax is supported by [97+% of all users browser (caniuse.com)](https://caniuse.com/#search=javascript%20modules).

Documentation:

- [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)
- [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)
- [Very good article on how to use module in browsers](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/)

Comment: Is it necessary to import 'module-a.mjs' first in order to use it in the module 'module-b.mjs'?

Answer (score 1):

The issue, as you said is that import is currently only being supported globally via Node. If you want to quickly import code on the client side, and jQuery is an option, then you can use:

```
$.getScript( "ajax/test.js" )
.done(function( script, textStatus ) {
    console.log( textStatus );
})
.fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
    $( "div.log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxError handler." );
});
```

This will load and execute the JavaScript code from the server. The callback `done` is called when the script has finished downloading, but not necessarily completed execution.

For more info, you can look at the [official reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

Answer (score 0):

This method for loading modules locally (i.e. client-side) unfortunately gets blocked by CORS in Chrome and Chromium based browsers.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
const url = './demo.js';
try { import(url).loadPageInto(main);} 
catch (error) { main.textContent = error.message; }
```